# How to manage delegate of WinForms buttons created at run-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Let's look at the following code in which I'm creating a List of buttons.

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.Button> buttons = new List<System.Windows.Forms.Button>(); 

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    buttons.Add(  System.Windows.Forms.Button>()  );
    buttons[i].Name = "button_" + i.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Bt_windowClick);
}
```

The next part is where I'm confused. When this delegate is called I would like it to tell me which button was actually clicked. How would I do this?

```
void Bt_windowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I would like to get the name of the button that was clicked
}
```

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sender object is a button, which raised event. So, simply cast it to `Button` type:

```
void Bt_windowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    // use button
    MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
}
```